# How do you select next combo box selection automatically in x second?

Tags: c#, winforms

Using C#, windows form.

I am trying to make the program automatically select next item on combo box every x seconds and once it reaches the last one, it goes back to the first one on list. i got pretty much everything minus auto combo box selection part. :(

help please.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Z:\DSCF1661.jpg");

        DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");//Assuming Test is your Folder
        FileInfo[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf"); //Getting Text files

        comboBox1.DataSource = Files;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        timerset();
    }


    public void axSetting()
    {
        axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
        axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
        axAcroPDF1.setPageMode("none");
        axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
        axAcroPDF1.Show();
    }



    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"C:\temp\" + comboBox1.Text);
        axAcroPDF1.src = @"C:\temp\" + comboBox1.Text;
        axSetting();

    }
    //private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;


    public void comboBoxSelect()
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < comboBox1.Count) // this part... :(
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public void timerset()
    {
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 5000; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxSelect();
    }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of getting the system's idle time in the first place? What does that accomplish that your `timer1` can't?

Comment: This really seems like an [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are your actual functional requirements, and why did you choose to use the system's idle time? It's hard to give you an idea about "how to do it better" without knowing what the program _should_ do.

Comment: purpose of this is for making announcement program. It suppose to grab file from share folder and when announcer drops new file in share folder it displays this file on the screen. this pc will always be idle so every 10 seconds it's going to show next file. or I could use of select next item in combo box in every sec instead of using idle time since the pc is going to be idle all the time.

Comment: @shin777 if the pc is going to be idle anyway, why not just check every 10 seconds via Thread.Sleep(10000)? If you dont want your main thread blocked by the reading of the file or something you can just check for new files in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(combobox.SelectedIndex < (combobox.Items.Count -1))
{
    combobox.SelectedIndex += 1;
}
else
{
    combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: combobox.source.count isn't working..    I am using FileInfo and *.pdf to filter pdf file names from the folder and Source part isn't working. :(

Comment: Kay. Try .Length instead, and if this isn't working either take the filearray you used to specify the source.

Comment: combobox.maxlength seems to be working. now only problem is.. how do I make it to go back to the first one when it reaches to the last one?

Comment: I'll update my answer to tell you how. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Here, this should be your solution.

Comment: ok. and I would appreciate if we use thread.sleep(10000) instead as people above suggested. When I put thread.sleep(10000) under combobox.selectedindex += 1, application doesn't open at all.

Comment: Hmmm, if I got this right, you want it to simply select the next combobox item every 10 seconds?

Comment: yes, and updated answer doesn't seem to be working. it just gets stuck on last item on combobox. maybe it's because I put if/else inside idle time bracket.

Comment: Ah, sorry. SelectedIndex is zero indexed.

Comment: As for the timer thing. If you only want it to regularly select the next file every 10 seconds, then  setting  timer with autoset = true, 10  sec interval and hooking up the TimerElapsed event with above if-else-statement should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not healthy so  can't test this, but if you check idle time at each timer tick: if < 10000 then  stop 10 sec timer. else if = 10000 then start 10 sec timer. And the code in my answer goes into the Elapsed event of the 10 sec timer.

Comment: I got timer working but I think .maxlength part is wrong. it just grabs longest file name length from the list. if i pick other name from combo box, then it goes back to the longest name one after 10 seconds. :(

Comment: Ah, OK. Try this then: combobox.DataSource.Length or .DataSource.Count

Comment: both of them red lined. :(

Comment: Sorry, my brain is rather sluggish today. I'll remove my answer as this obviously wasn't what you needed.

Comment: If I feel better later or tomorrow I'll get back to you. I'm pretty sure that what you need is Files.Length() or Files.Length, but... Unsure.

Comment: lol.. it works. thanks. but once it reaches last pdf file, it gets System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error on comboBox.SelectedIndex += 1; part. it tries to grab index # 3 but it doesn't exit since I only put 3 files in folder.

Comment: Just take combobox.Items.Count -1 then - updated solution.

Comment: awesome it works. I wonder why pdf keep scrolls down automatically everytime it jumps to the next file though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What's the problem?